# How to reference one of multiple ng-bootstrap Accordions in Angular 9 typescript?

Tags: angular, accordion, ng-bootstrap

If this is my accordion:

```
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" id="group-1" [closeOthers]="true" activeIds="panelID-1">
  <ngb-panel id="panelID-1" title="Simple">
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      Some panel content
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

I can reference it in the component TypeScript like so:

```
@ViewChild('acc') accordionComponent: NgbAccordion;
...
this.accordionComponent.toggle('panelID-1');
```

But, what if the Accordion is rendered from one instance in a repeating group?  Instead of ViewChild, I'd use:

```
@ViewChildren('acc') accordionComponentList: QueryList<NgbAccordion>;
```

But then how does one find a particular Accordion in the QueryList?  The [ng-bootstrap Accordion Api](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/api) does not include an id property.

Comment: What makes the accordion instance unique? You could retrieve it by its index in the `QueryList`.

Comment: @ConnersFan a property of the repeating group instance makes the Accordion unique and it is used to assign a value to the Accordion's element ID.  If someone doesn't come up with some way of accessing this id from the accordionComponent, then I'll have to use the index as you suggest.

Comment: You could have two `QueryList`s, one with the components, the other with the component host elements. The latter would contain the elements with their `id`. But I don't think it would help much since you already know the index of the component that you are looking for, and you can get the component at that index in the `QueryList`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan  I believe your idea would work.  I find the Accordion element that matches the id and then use the element index to get the corresponding Accordion component.  Very nice.  Wish I had thought more about your first answer.  Covid fatigue.  ha ha

Comment: @ConnorsFan Your idea worked.  I encapsulated the Accordion in a div having the group ID, found the encapsulator div by ID, then used its index to reference its child Accordion component.